# How many suspensions can you get before you're banned from Xbox?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I've been getting suspensions on Xbox for communication. The reason why is because, when I make a group post, people like to troll me sometimes and report me for no reason. I've stopped making group posts to prevent this from happening anymore. But, I've already gotten two suspensions. How many can I get before I get banned?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's official policy is:

> We may permanently suspend your profile if we can no longer trust it due to a severe violation or if our attempts to correct repeated negative behaviors are unsuccessful. A permanent account suspension blocks your profile from accessing Xbox Live in any way.

[Types of Xbox enforcement actions](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/family-online-safety/enforcement/types-of-xbox-enforcement-actions)

Only Microsoft can answer specifically what that means, and odds are its proprietary anyway. The answer is almost definitely "it depends". Three suspensions in the first three weeks of a new account is very different from three suspensions, years apart, on a 10 year old account.

Comment: Or "best judgement basis"; it depends on policy and who is looking at your case (moderators at their sole discretion can override certain policies as those are just guidelines), especially if you've somehow managed to get a re-review.